# How do i know if something is primitive type after autoboxing?

Tags: java, reflection, autoboxing

I know there are a lot of quesitons about reflection and primitive types already, but i didn't really get the exact information i searched.
My Problem is following:
I want to invoke methods (through reflection) completely dynamical, that means i want to invoke them even if i dont exactly know the types of the parameters.

```
public Object invoke(Object objectContainingMethod,String methodName, Object...params) {
    Object result = null;
    int length = params.length;
    Class<?>[] paramTypes = new Class<?>[length];

    for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        paramTypes[i] = params[i].getClass();
    }

    try {
        Method method = objectContainingMethod.getClass().getMethod(methodName, paramTypes);
        // not hard coded like getMethod(methodName, String.class, int.class, double.class);
        result = method.invoke(objectContainingMethod, params);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | 
             IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | 
             InvocationTargetException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

(Didn't optimized anything yet so pls don't hate^^)
The problem is, the parameter for the method need to be converted in Object but when i do this you can't really detect anymore if it is a primitive type because of auto boxing.
Which happens when i try to call the Method "charAt" from the class *String* with an *int* parameter:

```
String instance = "hello";
Object result = invoke(instance,"charAt",0);
```

which obviously results in:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.String.charAt(java.lang.Integer)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)...
```

He searched for *Integer* instead of *int* because of auto-boxing.
So is there a work around for what i'm trying to do here? I know how to detect primitive types, but not when they are auto-boxed to their wrapper types. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @sara not on point for this question. The example code has an extra layer of encapsulation that is hiding the object type via autoboxing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to pass a Class array as an argument in to your custom `invoke` method that has the explicit types to search for in the method signature instead of trying to determine types from the parameters directly. This is exactly why `Class.getMethod(String, Class[])` requires the types instead of inferring from parameters.

Change your signature to something like this. Use the class array directly, instead of inferring types. Alternatively you could us a Collection instead of an array, this is merely for example.

```
public Object invoke(Object objectContainingMethod,String methodName, Class<?>[] types, Object...params)
```

Comment: Now that i look at it it seems pretty obvious, lol. I guess i just have to determine which classes should be put in the array when im processing each parameter ( when i get an int, i put int.class in there etc.). Thank you and sorry for wasting your time ^^.

Comment: @Alastorftw When you get an int, you'll use `Integer.TYPE` as the class to denote the primitive `int` (not int.class as you commented, and not Integer.class).

Comment: Correction: `int.class` will work just the same as `Integer.TYPE`. However, `Integer.class` will still fail.